# How to solve invalid Operation Exception in xml deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

i wan to make deserialization my below xml But it produces error: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). Inner Exception: {" was not expected."}

How can i Deserialize my xml code? How can i solve below error?

MY C# code:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetData();
    }

    static void GetData()
    {
        string actionUrl = "http://test/vrm_search?q=56071794482024887&vrm_type=corvus";

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(actionUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Accept = "application/xml";


        string responseData = string.Empty;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(responseData);
                reader.Close();
            }

            response.Close();
        }

        Response res = XML.Deserialize<Response>(responseData);

        Console.Read();
    }

}


public static class XML
{

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

        using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
            {
                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ERROR:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looking for an "x" element, not an "x" element in the xml. (note the casing)

Comment: Your XML has a lower case "equipment_list" element. But your  XmlElement on Response.Equipment_List is title-cased. The xml serialization stuff is case sensitive, so you will need to fix the casing on either the xml or your XmlElement attributes to fix the error.

Comment: Did you try setting both Created and Equipment_list to be case sensitive: "created" and "equipment_list"

Comment: @Penguen, after your edit this answer no longer makes sense. Please fix or delete the question as it will not serve any purpose if anyone having a similar problem finds this page.